# Equivalent definitions of Fano variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a projective variety $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$, Harris defines the Fano variety of $k$-planes contained in $X$ as:
$$
F_k(X)=\{\Lambda:\Lambda\subseteq X\}\subseteq Gr(k,n).
$$
On the other hand, a lot of sources (like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_variety)) define a Fano variety to be a complete (let's say projective) variety whose anticanonical bundle is ample.

I'd like to know the exact relation between these definitions, either in an answer or references.

I'd imagine any variety of the first kind satisfies the second condition (can this be shown in an answer?), but I'm not sure if it's reasonable to expect a variety with ample anticanonical bundle to be necessarily of the first kind for some $X$ and $k$, or even to be a subvariety of a Grassmannian.

Comment: The only relation between the two notions is that both are named after Gino Fano.

Comment: @Sasha oh, really? I guess the second one is the one that is most commonly referred to, right?

Comment: Really. Both notions are used quite frequently, so be careful to distinguish.

Comment: @Sasha cool, thanks!